# My program does not quit when the if statement tells it to return 0 in main

Tags: c++, function, console

C++ rookie here, I am making this text based RPG-ish game and at the title screen, there is a option to quit. This is coded in main() as:

```
int main() {
    bool main_menu = true;
    while(main_menu == true) {
        cout <<"\033[2J\033[1;1H";
        cout <<GRN"Welcome to Yhawn! The text RPG straight outta 1972.\n";
        cout <<"\n";
        cout <<"(N)ew\n(Q)uit\n";
        cout <<"> ";
        std::string main_menu_select;
        std::cin >>main_menu_select;
        if(main_menu_select == "N" || main_menu_select == "n") {
            createNewCharacter();
            main_menu = false;
        // error is here
        if(main_menu_select == "Q" || main_menu_select == "q") {
            main_menu = false;
            return 0;
            }
```

But, on the title screen, it does not take `q` or `Q` as an input and just loops back. This is confusing me as `N` works just fine, and has the same code.

Thanks for any help you may give.

Comment: Just before anyone recommends this: I have already done `void quit()` (with no code inside) but that does not work as well.

Comment: `quit` has absolutely nothing to do with the posted code. It will never be called (and doesn't do anything, even if it were). Indentation does not equate to scope. The `Q` case is never hit, *ever* because it's buried in the `N` block. If the `N` block conditionally tests `true`, that ensures the nested `Q` block conditional test cannot possibly be true. In short, you're missing at least one closing `}` in this code, and in fact, to get a successful compile, you're missing at least *two* `}`. As presented, this code cannot *compile* much less run, so kindly update to a [mcve].

Comment: Updated your posted code with proper indentation to demonstrate where the aforementioned problem resides. No code was functionally changed.

Comment: updated the code as it still does not work.

Comment: Oh I'm dumb, it works now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that `quit()` function as written does exactly nothing. The statement `return 0;` in it doesn't end the whole program but just this (otherwise empty) function.

The simplest way to do what you seek is to replace the call to this function with `return 0;` like this

```
    if(main_menu_select == "Q" || main_menu_select == "q") {
      //quit();
      //main_menu = false;
      return 0;
    }
```

You can of course remove the lines I commented out as well as the useless `quit()` function.

Comment: And what WhozCraig says is all true too.

Comment: Note that `main_menu = false` will work just as well.

Comment: Read WhozCraig's comment about ```Q``` block being buried in the ```N``` block, he's explaining why you get the behavior you do.

Comment: 1) I knew that. I didn't comment on the original post because I saw WhozCraig's comment 2) Please realize I'm not the original question asker. I'm merely trying to help you improve your answer.

Comment: Yes, I see all that. I just don't have enough reputation to be allowed to comment on the original question, so I wrote my comment here. I should have made clear it was meant as a comment to the original question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The importance of correct tabbing is apparent in this code:

```
if(main_menu_select == "N" || main_menu_select == "n") {
    createNewCharacter();
    main_menu = false;
// error is here
if(main_menu_select == "Q" || main_menu_select == "q") {
    main_menu = false;
    return 0;
    }
```

Here is the code tabbed:

```
if(main_menu_select == "N" || main_menu_select == "n")
{
    createNewCharacter();
    main_menu = false;
    // error is here
    if(main_menu_select == "Q" || main_menu_select == "q") 
    {
        main_menu = false;
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem becomes evident: Missing closing '}' in the N condition resulting in Q condition being inside N condition which is impossible to trigger.